# Last X entries for a set of users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an transaction/audit table where an entry is created for each specific user action.

I am trying to pull the last transaction for a set of users. so for users 1,2,3 I am looking 
for the what each did last.

the basic schema is: trans_id, action, user_id

My first attempt at this was to do a query like so:

```
select * from audit_table where user_id IN (1,2,3) group_by(user_id) ORDER BY trans_id DESC
LIMIT 3
```

But this didn't specifically pull in the 'last' 3 entries.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT x.* 
      FROM audit_table x
      JOIN SELECT user_id, MAX(trans_id) max_trans_id FROM audit_table GROUP BY user_id) y
        ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
       AND y.max_trans_id = x.trans_id
     WHERE x.user_id IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Will only get the last trans_id for each user, but this is your best solution for multiple users

Comment: Yes. The thread title and the thread content suggest two differing requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this answer,  gave me the exact info I needed.

Comment: Dont forget to mark the answer as correct if it meets your requirements.